# facebook ads api ErrorException

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5.4, facebook-ads-api, facebook-insights

Im trying to get facebook ads api data using code in my laravel environtment, and I get this error

> Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT' in CurlLogger.php (line 83)

That `CurlLogger.php (line 83)` is a file from FacebookAds which have code like this :

```
   /**
   * @param resource $handle
   */
  public function __construct($handle = null) {
    $this->handle = is_resource($handle) ? $handle : STDOUT;
  }
```

I have already searched the solution in google and facebook, but didn't get the answer. What I need to solve this problem ?

Thank You.